# Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator' not found

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

Here is my code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\news;
use App\productions;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        $q = $request->q;
        $page = Input::get('page', 1);
        $paginate = 5;

        $first = DB::table('news')
            ->select(['id', 'title', 'description', 'imgPath'])
            ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
                $query->where('title', 'like', "%$q")
                    ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%$q");
            });

        $result = DB::table('productions')
            ->select(['id', 'title', 'description', 'imgPath'])
            ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
                $query->where('title', 'like', "%$q")
                    ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%$q");
            })
            ->unionAll($first)
            ->get();

        $slice = array_slice($result, $paginate * ($page - 1), $paginate);
        $results = Paginator::make($slice, count($result), $paginate);


        return view('search', compact('results'));
    }
}
```

When I run it, it throws this error:

> Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator' not found

**Note:** I use *Laravel Framework version 5.2.45*.

How can I fix it?

Comment: There is no Pagination Facade, check out the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change it to:

```
$results = new \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator($parameters);
```

Comment: Now it throws this: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::make()`

Comment: `$results = new Paginator($slice, count($result), $paginate);` ?

Comment: @pudov.maxim It throws: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Paginator' not found`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin your update version throws this: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator' not found`

Comment: Try to use full path: \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator

Comment: I did, the result: `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\ageofcyber\ageofcyber\app\Http\Controllers\SearchController.php on line 36 and defined`

Comment: Try to do that without Facade, but as described in the documentation (see updated code). Also, you can find an example here: http://laravel.io/forum/02-08-2015-how-do-i-manually-create-a-paginator-in-5?page=1#reply-27916

Comment: now the error gone .. And I'm trying to use the results .. thank you .. upvote

Answer (score 8):

Change your this code `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator` to `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`

And hopefully, it will work.

Comment: This answer is the first version of @AlexeyMezenin's answer *(which won't work)*

Comment: JFI - The first version of @AlexeyMezenin's answer has use(new Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator)->make(...) which will not work as there is no `make()` function in Paginator::class.

Comment: JFI - what you said is the **second** version of @AlexeyMezenin's answer. The first version of his answer is exactly the same as yours https://i.stack.imgur.com/afkQX.png

Comment: Oh my mistake, on my screen that version was collapsed. I hope your problem is solved now.

Comment: Works fine on my laravel 8 app.

Answer (score 1):

Add this,

```
  use \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

Then it will work

Comment: Thanks, it solved `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;`